# WS2812b with Wemos D1 Mini: first LED has a constant color, further ones stay dark

Tags: arduino, esp8266, led-strip, ws2812b

I'm trying to connect a WS2812b LED strip to a Wemos D1 Mini. I'm powering the strip from the 5V pin of the D1 (which is powered from USB). The data pin of the first LED is connected through a [level shifter](https://nettigo.pl/products/konwerter-poziomow-logicznych-dwukierunkowy-4-ro-kanalowy) which (I understand from the schematic) is based on the BSS138 MOSFET (I also tried connecting directly to a MCU pin with identical results). No other components (passive or active) are present.

I'm connecting the full 5m strip right now. I know there's zero chance I can power all these through USB but at least the first few LEDs should work, right? (I've specified the number of LEDs as 3 in the code).

I tried Adafruit_NeoPixel and FastLED with identical results, i.e. after `strip.begin()` (which just sets the output pin to low), the first LED lights up with what looks like always the same color, regardless of what I request later via `strip.show()` (some blue and a barely visible speck of red and green). Subsequent LEDs stay dark.

I tried setting the type to all combinations of BGR/RGB and 400/800 KHz, to no effect.

What can I do to diagnose this? I don't have any fancy hardware like an oscilloscope but can probably get access to one if everything else fails. I do have a multimeter at least.

**Note**: during my experiments I managed to short 5V and GND for a moment, letting the magic smoke out of the D1. I really hope I haven't burned the strip too but since the first LED still lights up (with a new D1), I assume it's still working. If I did fry it, is there a way to know/estimate/guess how many LEDs were affected? The strip is IP65-sealed so it's probably going to be a pain to cut and solder (I will have to at some point but I'm pushing it back as far as I can ;))

Comment: Show your wiring diagram else it's hard to give advice. Also do not try to power more than a handful of diodes off of the D1. Get a separate power supply

Comment: The D1 is a 3.3V device while the ws2812 is 5v, so using a level shifter is a good idea.